# @font-face not working in Firefox 10 / IE

Tags: font-face

I seriously have no idea why it's not working.  Currently not working in Firefox/IE only Safari/Chrome.

Using Google Web Fonts API
Here's the site:

Here's the code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I tried not using the Google API and just hosting the files on my server and it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not applying it to anything, you're only loading the javascript.

h1 {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

Just tried and it works.

Comment: I'm applying it to a number of elements (eg the navigation) on this page

Comment: #nav li a { background: none; color: #b8b7b7; font: 11px normal "Open Sans", sans-serif; text-decoration: none; }

Comment: Ok that's weird.  Apparently Firefox doesn't like when I use font.  But it works for font-family,  thanks!

Comment: a good tip is if it doesnt show up in firebug, then its not 'reading' the property, so either something was typed wrong or you used the property wrong. I didn't see it in chrome inspector either though, so that wasnt a chrome specific issue i dont think.